# Xcode Error: Incompatible Objective-C types. Expected 'struct UIView'

Tags: iphone, xcode, multiview

I am starting a multiview app with two views: NewGame and Players. I thought I was setting everything up properly, but apparently not.

**MainViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class NewGame; @class Players;

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet NewGame *newGameController;
    IBOutlet Players *playersController;
}

-(IBAction) loadNewGame:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) loadPlayers:(id)sender;

-(void) clearView;

@end
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "NewGame.h"
#import "Players.h"

@implementation MainViewController

-(IBAction) loadNewGame:(id)sender {
    [self clearView];
    [self.view insertSubview:newGameController atIndex:0];
}

-(IBAction) loadPlayers:(id)sender {
    [self clearView];
    [self.view insertSubview:playersController atIndex:0];
}

-(void) clearView {
    if (newGameController.view.superview) {
        [newGameController.view removeFromSuperview];
    } else if (playersController.view.superview) {
        [playersController.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self loadNewGame:nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

A couple of images...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwXMa.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHktH.png

Comment: Code blocks are denoted with four spaces per line, not `>`. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Views* are objects that represent what appears on screen.  *View controllers* are objects that perform application logic relating to those views.  A *view hierarchy* is a collection of views.  You are attempting to add a view controller to a view hierarchy as if it were actually a view.

Roughly speaking, you should have one view controller for every "screen" of your app.  This view controller can manage any number of views.  Its main view is accessible through its `view` property.

A quick fix to get your application operational would be to add the main view of your view controllers instead of the view controllers themselves.  So, for example, this:

```
[self.view insertSubview:playersController atIndex:0];
```

...would become this:

```
[self.view insertSubview:playersController.view atIndex:0];
```

Having said that, this is not a good solution long-term, and you should investigate a more structured way of organising transitions from view controller to view controller.  `UINavigationController` is a good option for beginners.

Comment: Yeah... I was missing the .view from the controller. Thank you.

Comment: New here. Hit return and it submitted the comment. Ha. And I appreciate the tip on a more structured way. I'm definitely a beginner.

Comment: Jim - I decided to not use multiple view controllers and go with one view controller and multiple views. I know how to load the views, but how can I clear them? The code is executing to insertSubview properly, but since there's already a view in place nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose playerController is view controller. Then add

```
[self.view addSubview: playerController.view];
```

OR if not then subclass them for UIView

Answer (score 0):

NewGame and Players both need to subclass UIView. If they're ViewControllers, not UIViews, you'll need to use newGameController.view instead of newGameController.